# How to detect old Opera via JavaScript (non-Webkit, non-Next, version 14-)

Tags: javascript, opera, browser-detection

Non-Webkit Opera was [very specific](http://caniuse.com) in some features, so it was usually detected via JavaScript [the following way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998293/how-to-determine-the-opera-browser-using-javascript).

However, Opera Next seeps to be almost a Google Chrome clone.

How can I target old Opera and not target Opera Next?

---

PS: I really do know that browser detection sucks and feature detection rules. But I hope to update the big and running project with a tiny browser-detection-patch rather then to rewrite tons of code into feature-detection paradigm.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problem source. It was in bad browser detection in that project. If you detect Opera exactly like in [the link given in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998293/how-to-determine-the-opera-browser-using-javascript), Opera Next is not detected to be Opera, so Old-Opera-Specific code is not executed, and Chrome-Specific-Code runs instead.

```
 !!window.opera;                      // true in old Opera, false in Opera Next

 navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera");//   -------    the same    --------
```

PS: Fortunately, I have lots of tests on my project, so I can tell that in new Opera things are working exactly as in Google Chrome.

A piece of code that caused problems tried to detect Opera Old AND Opera Next:

```
/(Opera|OPR)/.test(navigator.userAgent)
```

**Conclusion:** Opera migration was made very well, nothing should break in your projects. Do not detect Opera Next and simply treat it as usual Google Chrome.

UPDATE: previous Opera versions had gone from caniuse.com