# Get Current Browser Name using Jquery code

Tags: jquery

Actually, When I am using navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(), I get output like this :

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
```

I don't want this output. But I want to get only current browser name on which I am browsing and get browser name using Jquery.
Is there any function to get only current browser name instead of getting all browser names.
And, I get output "Chrome" when I am browsing on Google Chrome browser and, Firefox when I am browsing using Firefox Browser. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May i ask why would you need to know the current browser name? Usually, browser detecting is bad idea

Comment: Actually I want to show mp4 on firefox which is not work but i have equivalent gif images so When page opens at chrome i will show mp4 and when the same page opens in firefox i will show gif image which is actually converted from the mp4.

Comment: So you are looking for feature detection instead because anyway in the future FF could support mp4 format). See maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572113/how-to-check-if-the-browser-can-play-mp4-via-html5-video-tag

Comment: Actually, I have tested that above code give by you but is always gives the output true

Comment: Already has solution on Stack overflow
[click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352522/how-can-i-detect-browser-type-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
Object.keys(jQuery.browser)[0]
```

Before you used this you must be load this jquery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.3.0.js"></script>
```

because *jQuery.browser* Will not work in *jQuery 1.9* or later unless the jQuery Migrate plugin is included.

Comment: This works for chrome and firefox only but when this code runs on opera then it will give result chrome

Comment: It works for all browsers except opera. In opera, output is chrome.

Comment: Can I know that particular mp4 is playable or not in browser using javascript or jqyery

Comment: Please check this for opera :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998293/how-to-determine-the-opera-browser-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can search for browser like this:

```
// Check for Chrome
  if ($.browser.chrome) {
    alert("This is Chrome!");
  }
// Check for IE
  else if($.browser.msie)){
    alert("This is Internet Explorer!");
  }
// Check for Safari
  else if($.browser.safari)){
    alert("This is Safari!");
  }
```

Comment: No for jq **before** 1.9

Comment: I am still on the same starting point I don't get any kind of clue.
Actually I want single browser name which is in currently use instead of browser list.

Comment: why not using javascript, it is very easy in javascript.

Comment: so tell me in js or in jquery there is no problem I need a solution for that

Comment: If I added the code for opera in above code like this :
if ($.browser.opera) {
    alert("This is Opera!");
  }
Then, I also get output chrome instead of opera