# How to get browser name using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the name of browser i am using.Currently i am trying 'navigator.userAgent' but it shows 'chrome' for both edge and chrome browser.

Comment: **You can find the solutions on this **
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547312/get-current-browser-name-using-jquery-code)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is working I am too using it .It will show perfect browser name .Here is the  [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9atsffau/)

```
var isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
    // Firefox 1.0+
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
    // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
    // Internet Explorer 6-11
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
    // Edge 20+
var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
    // Chrome 1+
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
    // Blink engine detection
var isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;
```

Comment: Worked for me too.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to detect is [jquery-migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) with minimum and tested code which is designed to resolve any compatibility issues before using jQuery Migrate 3.0 and upgrading to jQuery 3.0.

```
if($.browser.mozilla) {

} 
else if($.browser.chrome) {

} 
... go on
```